# Libgdx fileHandle.writeString extraordinarily slow

Tags: java, file-io, libgdx

I have used fileHandle.writeString to a file to export my game's saves to a file. However I found that it is extraordinarily slow.

Running on desktop, it takes about 10 minutes to save 5 files with 15000 characters

Is there a way to speed things up or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
Here is writeString is used

```
private void export(int num) {
    if(Gdx.files.isLocalStorageAvailable()) {
        String name = "maps/map.MAP";
        FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.local(name);
        if(Gdx.files.local(name).exists())
            fileHandle.writeString("", false);
        for(int y = 0; y<= height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++) {
                fileHandle.writeString(""+map[0][x][y] , true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code where fileHandle.writeString is used, so we can determine if the problem originates from the libGDX framework or the way you are using it.

Comment: Too many calls to writestring. Why don't you append the string first and then use only one wrtiestring call.

Comment: With only one writeString call, i'm able to write 1000000+ characters in a few seconds on both Android & Desktop.
If you have large maps, also consider compressing the string data to reduce the file size. (With compression i'm able to divide saved map file size in my game by 25)

Comment: Lestat and Khopa are both right! I am calling writeString too many times!